# How to count and sum total of DataTable with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable which has a column "amount" for each rows and I'd like to have the total sum of all the rows. And also, I'd like to get total number of rows in the DataTable. Could anyone teach me how to have it done with LINQ instead of ordinary way?

Comment: How do you define "ordinary way"?

Comment: Ordinary way as in looping through each row and do the sum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Number of rows:

```
DataTable dt; // ... populate DataTable
var count = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Sum of the "amount" column:

```
DataTable dt; // ... populate DataTable
var sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => dr.Field<int>("amount"));
```

Comment: You don't need `AsEnumerable` or `Select`.  You can pass the lambda directly to `Sum`.

Comment: @recursive `DataTable` does not have an extension method called `Sum` - that's why the `AsEnumerable` is needed. I agree with the other suggestion though and I've edited my answer in response.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  My mistake.  I never understood what `AsEnumerable` was for.  Apparently, I've never used `DataTable`s.

Comment: @recursive No worries. Don't know why MS didn't retroactively implement IEnumerable<DataRow> on DataTable in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate allows you to avoid enumerating the rows twice (you could get the row count from the rows collection but this is more to show how to extract multiple aggregates in 1 pass):

```
var sumAndCount = table.AsEnumerable().Aggregate(new { Sum = 0d, Count = 0}, 
                                  (data, row) => new { Sum = data.Sum + row.Field<double>("amount"), Count = data.Count + 1});

double sum = sumAndCount.Sum;
int count = sumAndCount.Count;
```

Comment: loving this! I had completely missed the aggregate extension method before

Comment: @DarenFox Yes, IMHO it is one of the most underused linq operator

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal[] Amount = {2,3,5 };
var sum = Amount.Sum();
var count = Amount.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Roy Goode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174030/1993545)'s Answer you could also create an Extension

```
    public static int Sum(this DataTable table, string Column)
    {
        return table.AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => dr.Field<int>(Column));
    }
```

Unfortunately you can't be more generic her because there is no `where T : numeric`